# How to restore data from single bak file which contain multiple mdf file in 2008R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-backups

i have multiple mdf files inside a single bak file how can I restore bak file in database.

Answer (score 1):

Run `restore headeronly` to list the backup sets in the file (device), then `restore filelistonly` to see the details of the backup set you want to restore, then `restore database` targeting the selected backup set.

```
--create the backup file
backup database adventureworks2017 to disk='c:\temp\aw.bak' with format, init

--append some more backups to the file
backup database adventureworks2017 to disk='c:\temp\aw.bak' 
backup database adventureworks2017 to disk='c:\temp\aw.bak' 

restore headeronly from disk='c:\temp\aw.bak' 

restore filelistonly from disk='c:\temp\aw.bak' with file=2

restore database adventureworks2017 from disk='c:\temp\aw.bak' with file=2
```

Comment: I am getting the error can u help  Msg 3154, Level 16, State 4, Line 6
The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'ABCDB' database.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.IT has 3 mdf file with abcdb,abcdb_index,abcdb_mac and one log file abcdb_log

Comment: That error is warning you that you are trying to overwrite a database with a backup taken of a different database.  If that is what you want, you have to specify WITH REPLACE in the RESTORE command.  See  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#REPLACEoption

Answer (score 0):

you can run that command to see the file list of your bak file:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK ='<path>\<yourfile.bak>'
```

After you see the files you can build a restore command like that (just as sample):

```
restore database [db_name] from disk = '<file>.bak'
with 
move '<data_file_name>' to 'D:\MSSQL\Data\<file>.mdf',
move '<log_file_name>' to 'D:\MSSQL\Data\<file>.ldf'
```